# Recursion for a given series reversion

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

- Define the operator $\operatorname{SR}$, which is associated with the [series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html).
- Let $a(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence with generating function
  $$
  \frac{1}{x}\operatorname{SR}(x\frac{1-mx}{1-kx})
  $$
- Let
  $$
  u(n,q,m,k)=mu(n-1,q-1,m,k)+k\sum\limits_{j=q}^{n-1}u(n-1,j,m,k), \\
  u(0,0,m,k)=1
  $$
  Let $b(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
  $$
  b(n,m,k)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} u(n,j,m,k)
  $$

I conjecture that $$a(n,m,k)=b(n,m-k,m)$$.

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
a(n, m, k)=polcoeff(1/x*serreverse(x*(1-m*x)/(1-k*x) + x^2*O(x^n)), n)
b_upto(n, m, k)=my(v1, v2, v3); v1=vector(n+1, i, 0); v1[1]=1; v2=v1; v3=vector(n+1, i, 0); v3[1]=1; for(i=1, n, for(j=1, i, v2[j+1]=m*v1[j] + k*sum(s=j, i-1, v1[s+1])); v2[1]=0; v1=v2; v3[i+1]=vecsum(v1)); v3
test(n)=vector(n+1, i, a(i-1, m, k))==b_upto(n, m-k, m)
```

Is there a way to prove it?